# sorting the content of an object with javascript

Tags: javascript

if I have an object that looks like:

```
let object = {
  name1 : {
    number : .5,
    otherVar : 'something'
  }, 
  name2 : {
    number : .7,
    otherVar : 'text'
  },
  name3 : {
    number : -.1,
    otherVar : 'some words'
  }
};
```

how could I sort it by the number value and get an array:[ name3, name1, name2]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another es6 exampel:

```js
let object = {
  name1 : {
    number : .5,
    otherVar : 'something'
  }, 
  name2 : {
    number : .7,
    otherVar : 'text'
  },
  name3 : {
    number : -.1,
    otherVar : 'some words'
  }
};

let k = Object.keys(object).sort(((a, b) => object[a].number > object[b].number));
console.log(k);
```

Comment: that's a really nice inline solution, that rules :)

Comment: My solution wasn't so awsome, that's why a liked it more, I learned now how to do it :D

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one liner:

```
Object.keys(object).map(key => object[key]).sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number)
```

Comment: Niiiiiice one! must be the top ;)

Answer (score 2):

`let sorted = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]).sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number);`

**Explanation:**

- `Object.keys(obj)` will return an array of keys `['name1', 'name2'...]`
- `.map` will turn that array into an array of values
- `.sort` takes a compare function and returns the sorted array (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort))

Recommendation: don't call your objects `object` :)

Comment: Okey, here is an example of a perfect answer. Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: actually this is not quite what i was looking for, i want to get an array of the keys, not he objects at the key, so instead of [{number : -.1,..} .. i want ['name3', 'name1'..

Comment: Thanks @DamianLattenero. To get just the names, you can re-map the resulting array, and get the key names.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array that contains the object properties with the names added to them:

```
var array = [];
for (var key in object) {
    object[key].name = key;
    array.push(object[key]);
}
```

Then sort that array by the number:

```
array.sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number);
```

Then get the names out of the array:

```
var sortedNames = array.map(e => e.name);
```

Full demo:

```js
let object = {
  name1 : {
    number : .5,
    otherVar : 'something'
  }, 
  name2 : {
    number : .7,
    otherVar : 'text'
  },
  name3 : {
    number : -.1,
    otherVar : 'some words'
  }
};

var array = [];
for (var key in object) {
    object[key].name = key;
    array.push(object[key]);
}
array.sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number);
var sortedNames = array.map(e => e.name);
console.log(sortedNames);
```

Comment: wooooow, that's awsome, clever as far... :) thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

It should do the dirty work, first you flat your object into an array of objects, then you create your custom compare function, finally sort, and voila!

```
var keys = Object.keys(object);

function compare(a,b) {
  if (object[a].number < object[b].number)
    return -1;
  if (object[a].number > object[b].number)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
var res = keys.sort(compare);
```

Comment: This won't work. There's no `number` property in the keys.

Comment: Yeaaah @Barmar good eyes! you were absolutly right! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var items = [];
items = JSON.parse(object);
}); //will give you an array

function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.number < b.number)
    return -1;
  if (a.number > b.number)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
items.sort(compare); //array will be sorted by number
```

Comment: How will `JSON.parse(object)` give you an array?

Comment: It is close enough, but why don't you use the keys() functions to get the array?